# remove last element of a list sml by keeping the list in a val

Tags: sml, ml

How can I remove the last element in a list in *Standard ML*?
I have a list defined as:

```
val list = [1, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

and I want to remove the last element and have the list in the `val list`.

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you have various ways of doing it.

- You could take the original list apart, and start building a new list with the elements, until you reach the last element.

  ```
  fun f [] = ...
    | f [x] = ...
    | f (x::xs) = x :: ...
  ```
- Or you could use the [List.take](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.take:VAL) function to take the first i elements from the list. Obviously you could use [the List.length](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.length:VAL) function to calculate how many elements you wan't to take from the list.

  ```
  fun h xs = List.take (xs, ...)
  ```

Comment: yes but this is an example,i want to create a function that takes a list and returns the list without the las element.

Comment: And I have given you two fine examples of how to do this.